# Add and remove integer count dynamically in android

Tags: android, view

I have created the add and remove view dynamically.Everything works fine.In that view have add the two textview one for message and another one for displaying the message count.If i add the message, the count will be increased and it will be set text on 1st textview. If I remove the view, the whole view get removed.And then i want to change the count value in textview.But that value not changed.`

```
buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.question_row, null);
                final TextView count1 = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
                TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.count1);
                textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());
                count++;
                count1.setText(""+count);
                textIn.setText("");


                Log.d("count---",""+count);

                Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        count1.setText("");
                        ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                        count--;
                        Log.d("count---",""+count);
                        count1.setText(""+count);
                    }});

                container.addView(addView);
            }

        });
```

In the 1st image i have add the 5 view. and the count value get increased accordingly

[image: add view dynamically]

In the second image i have removed the 3rd item that 3rd item get removed. The count remains as 1,2,4,5.But i need the count value as 1,2,3,4.What to do for updating this one?
[image: remove view dynamically]

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove a row, you need to update all the child views below the one that you removed. So you need to iterate through all your children.

```
buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    count--;
                    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)addView.getParent();
                    ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                        View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
                            (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count1).setText((i + 1) + "");
                        }
                    }
                }});
```

Comment: No changes happen it remains as it as @rhari

Comment: I made some changes, can you try again please ?

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: same thing the count not updated after removing the view